# JSON Parsing (swift)

Tags: ios, json, struct

I am trying parse this JSON

```
["Items": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x61000001ec20>(

{

    AccountBalance = 0;

    AlphabetType = 3;

    Description = "\U0631\U06cc\U0648";

    FullCode = "P_21_JIM_456_IR_25";

    IRNumber = 25;

    LeftNumber = 21;

    RightNumber = 456;

}

)

, "ErrorCode": 0, "ErrorMessage": , "Result": 1]
```

how can access to items parameter in this case? I'm trying create structure for Items but I have an this error : Cannot convert value of type '(key: String, value: AnyObject)' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]'
 what is solution for access Items parameter ?

there is my Items structure and parsing JSON code :

```
 struct PalletItems {

        let accountBalance : Int
        let alphabetType : Int
        let description : String
        let fullCode : String
        let irNumber : Int
        let leftNumber : Int
        let rightNumber : Int

        init? (accountBalance: Int, alphabetType: Int, description : String, fullCode: String, irNumber: Int, leftNumber: Int, rightNumber: Int ) {


            self.accountBalance = accountBalance
            self.alphabetType = alphabetType
            self.description = description
            self.fullCode = fullCode
            self.irNumber = irNumber
            self.leftNumber = leftNumber
            self.rightNumber = rightNumber

        }



func palletListFromJSONData(_ data : Data) -> PaletListResult {



        do{
            let jsonresult : [String : AnyObject]
                = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]
            print("json : \(jsonresult)")
             let success = jsonresult["Items"] as? PalletItems
            print("items is : \(success)")

            for paletJson in jsonresult {
                if let palet = getBalanceOfWalletFromJsonObject(paletJson) {

                    finalResult.append(palet)
                }
            }


            let palet = getBalanceOfWalletFromJsonObject(jsonresult)

            finalResult.append(palet!)

            return .success(finalResult)

        }

        catch let error as NSError{
            print("that is parsing json error : \(error)")

            return .failure(error)
        }
    }


    func getBalanceOfWalletFromJsonObject(_ json: [String: AnyObject]) -> ListOfPlates?{

        guard let
            errorCode = json["ErrorCode"] as? Int,
            let errorMessage = json["ErrorMessage"] as? String,
            let result = json["Result"] as? Int,
            let item = json["Items"] as? PalletItems

            else {
                return nil
        }
        let obj = ListOfPlates(errorCode: errorCode, errorMessage: errorMessage, result: result, items: item)

        return obj
    }
```

Comment: show some more code. how are you trying to parse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to access it as key value pair but you're getting it as an array. So the json should be of [[String:Any]]
Now this json should be parsed as json.first! which gives you [String:Any]. Now you can get the value of any key.

Comment: that's mean I don't have create structure for items ? and just with parsing JSON can access to items value ?

Comment: I am trying this but I have an error : Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x1013730b8) to 'NSArray' (0x101372c58). in line  let 
                = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [[String:Any]]

Comment: In the for loop it should be paletJson in success. Isn't?

Comment: my code crash in try JSONSerialization and not running for loop.

Comment: i'm print JSON with [string:any], but how access to items value ?

Comment: jsonresult["Items"] as? [[String:Any]]. Because items is coming as an array.

Comment: For those who like to see code:

`if let dict = result as? [String : Any], let Items = dict["Items"] as? [[String : Any]],
                let firstObj = data.first, let accountBalance = firstObj["accountBalance"] as? Int {
                print(accountBalance)
            }`